# iPhone touchmove bypass

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, touch

I am building a mobile website that contains fixed elements. Unfortunately the iPhone handles fixed elements as if they were static.
I know of a solution where you put that image into a scrollable div, so the elements stay at their position while you scroll. But then on the iPhone you have to use two fingers for scrolling which is very uncomfortable.

Can you show me a way to bind the two-finger-touchmove to one finger or switch the touchmove events?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into UIGestures. You can map one to multiples touches. You can also check what type of gesture it is. Eg. Panning, Pinching, Shake, Swipe right etc...

Comment: How do I begin? Is there some kind of reference?

Comment: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/event-handling/gestures-recognizers-tap-pinchzoom-rotate-swipe-pan-long-press.html